# javafx doesn't draw graph

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to draw a graph of currency changes. I take the data from a text file. The data looks like this.

```
09.12.2023 1 91.6402 98.8409 22.8068
10.12.2023 1 91.8103 99.0205 23.5067
11.12.2023 1 90.5367 98.0256 22.0023
```

the line consists of 5 parts: date, relation to the original currency, relation to the dollar, relation to the euro, relation to the zloty.

I prepare data like this, arraylist lines stores an array of lines from a file

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> prepareDataToDraw() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] tmpStr = new String[5];
    if (lines.size() > 5) {
        for(int i = lines.size()-1; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            tmpStr = lines.get(i).split(" ");
            ArrayList<String> tmpBlock = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpBlock.add(tmpStr[0]);
            tmpBlock.add(tmpStr[2]);
            tmpBlock.add(tmpStr[3]);
            tmpBlock.add(tmpStr[4]);
            data.add(tmpBlock);
        }
    } else {
        for (String line : lines) {
            tmpStr = line.split(" ");
            ArrayList<String> tmpBlock = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpBlock.add(tmpStr[0]);
            tmpBlock.add(tmpStr[2]);
            tmpBlock.add(tmpStr[3]);
            tmpBlock.add(tmpStr[4]);
            data.add(tmpBlock);
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

I'm trying to draw a graph using this function. The variable dates stores dates from the file

```
public void drawChart() {
        chart.setTitle("Country Summary");
        chart.setAxisSortingPolicy(LineChart.SortingPolicy.NONE);
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");
        dates.clear();
        cures.clear();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = par.prepareDataToDraw();
        xAxis.setCategories(dates);

        ArrayList<XYChart.Series> listSeries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < items.size(); i++) {
            XYChart.Series tmpSeries = new XYChart.Series();
            tmpSeries.setName(items.get(i));
            for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++) {
                tmpSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(data.get(j).get(0), Double.parseDouble(data.get(j).get(i))));
            }
            chart.getData().add(tmpSeries);
        }
```

the graph is defined in the fxml file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<GridPane hgap="15" vgap="15" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
    <ComboBox fx:id="fromCurrency" onAction="#changeFromCurrencyCombo" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
    <TextField fx:id="fromCurrencyText" onTextChange="#changeFromCurrencyText" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
    <Label fx:id="fromCurrencyLabel" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.columnIndex="2"></Label>
    <Button fx:id="swapButton" text="↔" GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" onAction="#swapButtonClicked"></Button>
    <ComboBox fx:id="toCurrency" onAction="#changeToCurrencyCombo" GridPane.rowIndex="7" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
    <Label fx:id="toCurrencyText"  GridPane.rowIndex="8" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/><!--onTextChange="#changeToCurrencyText"-->
    <Label fx:id="toCurrencyLabel" GridPane.rowIndex="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2"></Label>
    <LineChart fx:id="chart" GridPane.rowIndex="10" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
        <xAxis>
            <CategoryAxis fx:id="xAxis">
            </CategoryAxis>
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
            <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxis"/>
        </yAxis>
    </LineChart>
</GridPane>
```

The chart is not drawn and I also noticed that the order of the data is changing without my knowledge and tried to prevent this using `chart.setAxisSortingPolicy(LineChart.SortingPolicy.NONE);`
But the data still changes order
Window of program look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krqrc.png)

Comment: I find it strange you do `dates.clear()` just before `xAxis.setCategories(dates)`. Not sure if that's the problem though. May need a [mre].

Comment: My guess is that you are doing `Chart<...> chart = new Chart();`

Comment: Using dates.clear() I clear the dates because during initialization I add the element "a" there. I haven't found any other way to initialize empty dates.

Comment: `CategoryAxis` has some weird problems, at least when the chart is animated, if you don't have at least the same categories registered with it as show up in the chart data. This _might_ be the source of your problem (or it might not be).

Comment: Slaw, your comment about empty dates was correct. I didn’t notice that it doesn’t fill up at all afterwards. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

According to Slaw's comment, I will add data to dates like this

```
public void drawChart() {
        chart.setTitle("Country Summary");
        chart.setAxisSortingPolicy(LineChart.SortingPolicy.NONE);
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");
        dates.clear();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = par.prepareDataToDraw();
        for (ArrayList<String> tmpDates: data){
            dates.add(tmpDates.get(0));
        }
        xAxis.setCategories(dates);

        for (int i = 1; i < items.size(); i++) {
            XYChart.Series tmpSeries = new XYChart.Series();
            tmpSeries.setName(items.get(i));
            for (int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++) {
                tmpSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(data.get(j).get(0), Double.parseDouble(data.get(j).get(i))));
            }
            chart.getData().add(tmpSeries);
        }
    }
```

And everything worked